# ObjectiveResource and broken NSNumberFormatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application that uses [ObjectiveResource](http://iphoneonrails.com/) and has a class that contains NSNumber properties. I am trying to format the NSNumber values as integers, and have the following code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

NSLog(@"Price: %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:self.item.price])
NSLog(@"Price: %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.item.price doubleValue]]]);

[formatter release];
```

Which outputs:

> 2010-07-15 19:33:45.371
>   Sample[4193:207] alcohol: (null)
>   2010-07-15 19:33:45.453
>   Sample[4193:207] alcohol: $13.50

I'm not sure why the first item is outputting (null), yet the second works fine. I'd prefer to use the syntax from the first, and not have to re-create a NSNumber.

Comment: Is `price` declared as an `NSNumber *`? What is the result of just `NSLog(@"%@", self.item.price);`?

Comment: @warrenm Price is a NSNumber * and the result of NSLog(@"%@", self.item.price) is 13.5.

Comment: The first line works in my brief tests, so it seems like the culprit may lie beyond NSNumberFormatter. Have you tried registering for changes to `price` via KVO? Is its parent object being concurrently updated?

Comment: I don't think the parent object is being concurrently updated (however, I don't know the full details of ActiveResource). Also, I'm not sure how the KVO changes will help. Do you have any more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self.item.price is probably an NSString?

Through an awful hack I can reproduce your result exactly:

```
NSNumber *price = (NSNumber*)@"13.5"; // *shiver*, don't try this at home!
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

NSLog(@"Price: %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:price]);
NSLog(@"Price: %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[price doubleValue]]]);
```

Since `NSString` responds to `doubleValue`, this comes out:

```
2010-07-16 17:17:50.384 test[716:207] Price: (null)
2010-07-16 17:17:50.386 test[716:207] Price: $13.50
```

Comment: Thanks MVDS. That I took a look through the ActiveResource code and this is indeed the case. I added the fix below:

Answer (score 1):

To fix, in the XML Element Delegate (XMLElementDelegate.m) a section of code needed to be uncommented to support NSNumber. The line is:

```
// uncomment this if you what to support NSNumber and NSDecimalNumber
// if you do your classId must be a NSNumber since rails will pass it as such
else if ([type isEqualToString:@"decimal"]) {
    return [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:propertyValue];
}
else if ([type isEqualToString:@"integer"]) {
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:[propertyValue intValue]];
}
```